# How to enable Custom Icons on Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have custom icons that work fine on IOS and Android. When I deploy on the Web, a crossed out box appears in each place in the App where my icon should appear.

The error that appears in the console is the following:

> Could not find a set of Noto fonts to display all missing characters.
> Please add a font asset for the missing characters.

When I check the documentation on [Flutter Design Fonts](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts), I see that I have followed the steps.

My custom icons (`fishfarm.ttf`) are located at assets folder. In `pubspec.yaml` I have the following:

```
  fonts:
   - family: FishFarm
     fonts:
      - asset: assets/fishfarm.ttf
```

I can use my Icons in IOS and Android using `Icon(FishFarm.nombreicono)`

**How can I use custom icons in Flutter Web?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick fix is that build your web app using `html` renderer.

To build

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

or to run

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

But it might give poor performance on pc browsers because flutter web uses `canvaskit` renderer on pc browsers for better performance and `html` renderer for mobile browsers.

[See web renderers doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/web-renderers)

Comment: Hi @pradeep. Do you know any alternative to handle custom icons on PC Browsers without hurting performance?

Comment: it works for me. 

when I used '●' char for web it throw error:

Could not find a set of Noto fonts to display all missing characters. Please add a font asset for the missing characters.